RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded - Typescript
When I try to get the name of the Player class in index.ts I get the following error:
/Users/pp/Developer/Typescript/src/lib/player.ts:10
    public get name() { return this.name; }
                                    ^
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Player.get name [as name]

Here is the code:
lib/player.ts:
export class Player {
    private _name: string;

    constructor(name: string) {
        this._name = name;
    }

    public get name() { return this.name; }
    public set name(value: string) { this.name = value; }
}

index.ts:
import { Player } from './lib/player';

const player = new Player('name');
console.log(player.name);


Accessing this.name calls get name() which accesses this.name which calls get name() and so on ad infinitum.

Presumably you want return._name for the getter and this._name = value for the setter.

Duplicate of : JavaScript getters and setters - recursion issue

Accessing this.name calls get name() which accesses this.name which calls get name() and so on ad infinitum (or, until you exhaust the call stack).
You probably intended to do:
export class Player {
    private _name: string;
    
    constructor(name: string) {
        this._name = name;
    }
    
    public get name() { return this._name; }
    public set name(value: string) { this._name = value; }
}

